# CSharpCodeDomeProvider CS009: Metadata file could not be opened Metadata table InterfaceImpl not sorted

Tags: c#, runtime-compilation, system-codedom-compiler

**What I want**:
Compile C#-Scripts at runtime with Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider (latest from Nuget, new compiler)
instead with
Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider (old compiler).

**Why ?:**
Because I want to use c#7 Feature in my scripts.

**Problem ?:**
I have a problem with an obfuscated dll which is referenced by the script I want to compile, the compiler throws the "*CS009: Metadata file xxx.dll could not be opened  Metadata table InterfaceImpl not sorted*" error. When I didnt use obfuscation everything runs fine. The "old"-compiler runs fine with the obfuscated reference dll and dont complain about anything.

Is there a way to sort the Metadata table or a Flag which tells the compiler to ignore an unsorted Metadata table ?

Thank you in advance!